# Unity : Point in contact with an other solid

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to make my player "Jump", but only if the point at the bottom of the capsule collider is touching something.

So, I was wondering : is there a quick way with Unity to see if a point of one solid is in contact with an other solid ?

Thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 methods to do this

`1)OnCollisionEnter()`-called When the collision happens

`2)OnCollisionStay()` - called repeated while one object is touching other

believe for your case OnCollissionStay() will work

Reference:[1]http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html

Answer (score 0):

The "OnCollision", for many reasons, (glitch and stuff when ground is bouncy) is not the best option.

So I found the one I was searching for.

It's just using the "Physics.Raycast" function : doing so, with the origin set at the origin of the collider, and the direction "down", we can see if there is an object under our feet.